# Существует ли в русском языке слово НАДЁГА?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Существует ли в русском языке слово НАДЁГА? Можно ли его употреблять в значении "надёжность"? Например, "мне нужна от человека надёга, чтобы я чувствовала себя как за каменной стеной, чтобы была уверенность в завтрашнем дне".

Answer (score 1):

Бытование такого слова подтверждается единичными фактами, не попавшими в словари: «Была в них какая-то надега, прочность, какой нет на земле». *(Н. Дежнев. В концертном исполнении. 1993).*

Существует благозвучное НАДЁЖА, -и, ж. Обл. То же, что надежда. Народно-поэт. ласковое обращение к близкому, любимому человеку.

> Кормилец, надежа семьи! Очей бы с тебя не спускали, Ловили бы речи
> твои. *(Н. Некрасов)*
>
> Ты не верила, сквозь слезы улыбалася, Улыбаясь, обняла меня и молвила:
> «Не покинь меня, надежа, все я вынесу, при тебе и злое горе будет
> радостью». *(И. Никитин)*

*Из Словаря русского языка РАН, Ин-т лингвистич. исследований под ред. Евгеньевой. 1999*.

НАДЁЖА, и, мн. нет, ж. (простореч., нар.-поэт.). Надежда.

> Вся надежа была — словно вылитый в мать, темнорусый красавец-сынишка.
> И. Нктн.

*Толковый словарь русского языка под ред. Ушакова 1935-1940 (электронная версия).*

Употребление *надёги* в словосочетании «*нужна от человека надёга*» не соответствует его смыслу. Не *надёга*, она же *надежда* (вера в возможное), а *надёжность* (свойство, качество во времени) нужна людям в лице их близких.

Answer (score 1):

1. Слова "***надёга***"  в словарях нет, есть только "***надёжа***", а также "***безнадёга***". В то же время в устной речи оно используется, и вот интересный пример. Владимир Путин на Лебединском ГОКе:

*А Вы уверены в завтрашнем дне, вот Вы? Нет. Я серьезно, без всяких шуток, я хочу Ваши ощущения. Сейчас, знаете, я не шучу, по-серьезному спрашиваю, внутренние ощущения – Вы уверены, **надёга есть внутренняя**?" https://gubkin.city/news/policy/8802/

А это единственный пример из Нацкорпуса: *Была в них какая-то **надега,** прочность, какой нет на земле.* [Николай Дежнев. В концертном исполнении (1993)]

2. Слово "***надежа***" встречается в 253 примерах. По его употреблению можно сказать, что оно также используется  преимущественно в народно-разговорной речи, а вот в книжном стиле  заключается **в кавычки**, например:

*Скажем, через все русские сказки проходит такой персонаж, как ***«надежа-царь»***, который есть часть народа.* [Наталья Архангельская// «Эксперт», 06.12.2004]

*Кострома ― самая крепкая ***«надёжа»*** государственности русской, тайный алтарь святой монаршей идеи.* [Александр Зябликов. Провинциальная столица // «Сибирские огни», 2013]

3. Приведенное в вопросе предложение также построено по книжному образцу, поэтому  желательно **использовать кавычки**, чтобы не было стилевого несоответствия:

*Мне нужна от человека ***"надёга"***, чтобы я чувствовала себя как за каменной стеной, чтобы была уверенность в завтрашнем дне.*

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Надежа (надега) ― это надежда согласно словарю, но в других значениях тоже, вероятно,  может использоваться. *Кострома ― самая крепкая «надёжа» (опора) государственности русской...*  Здесь это мало похоже  на надежду, скорее опора.